# How do I remove the ValueError: Length of values (55) does not match length of index (100) in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I Have created a list whose length is 55. The list looks like

```
list1 = [1653423,6415453,..........14799324]
```

I have already created a dataframe and I want to add the list elements to the column 'A'. I am adding the list in the dataframe like

```
df['A'] = list1
df.explode('A')
```

However I got an `ValueError: Length of values (55) does not match length of index (100)`

I tried removing the error using pd.Series

```
df['A'] = pd.Series(list1)
df.explode('A')
```

However that didn't help either. How do I save the list values to my dataframe? Please help.

Comment: Adding a list to a dataframe in that manner `df['A'] = list1` already assumes that each element of the list will be a separate row.  Therefore, Pandas assumes the length of the list will match the "length" (number of rows) of the dataframe.  If you want more help, I suggest providing a [mcve].

Comment: it seems that there is mismatch size between `df` and `list1`, what is the shape of `df` ? this raised cause df has more rows that the ones you want to add.

Comment: @MiguelTrejo the size of df is 100 and list1 has 55.

Comment: @technophile_3 do you want to assign to each row of `df` in the column `A` the list `list1` and then explode that column for all the rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only assign the same length to the df

```
df.loc[:df.index[len(list1)-1],'A']=list1
```

Comment: So if the length of my df is 100 but this particular column's length is 55, what happens to the 45 records? Are they given NaN values or?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a df already with multiple columns, you can use `append`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['a','b','c']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': list1})
df1 = df1.append(df2)
```